# Sufficient and necessary condition for the continuity of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $f(\cdot) \in \mathscr{C}\left( \mathcal{D}; \mathbb{R} \right)$ where $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open with $0 \in \mathcal{D}$ and 
$$ f(0) = 0, \quad \forall x \in \mathcal{D}\setminus \{ 0 \}, \; xf(x) < 0.$$ My question is that is there a sufficient and necessary condition on the structure of $f(\cdot)$ which guarantees that

\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathcal{D}, \; \int_{x}^{0} \dfrac{1}{f(z)} \mathsf{d}z < + \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to 0} \int_{x}^{0} \dfrac{1}{f(z)} \mathsf{d}z = 0 
\end{equation}
are true? Note that $\int_{x}^{0} 1/f(z) \mathsf{d}z$ is an improper integral since $f(0) = 0$.

An example satisfying the above two conditions is $f(x) = -\mathsf{sign} (x) | x |^a $ with $\mathcal{D} = \mathbb{R}$ and $0 < a < 1$, which leads to

\begin{equation}
\int_{x}^{0} \dfrac{1}{f(z)} \mathsf{d}z = -\int_{x}^{0}  \dfrac{1}{\mathsf{sign} (z)| z |^a } \mathsf{d}z = | x |^{1-a} \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to 0} | x |^{1 - a} = 0.  
\end{equation}

Comment: Having $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{|f(z)|}\,dz < \infty$ is sufficient by the dominated convergence theorem, and likely pretty close to necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.